# Hadoop Job hangs at ACCEPTED, with yarn resourcemanager log java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, hadoop, hostname

As is described in the title, I deployed a hadoop v2.6.3 cluster on an internal network with static ip like 10.0.0.x.
Then I ran an example [WordCount Program](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Source_Code) However, the shell just give the outputs and hangs:

```
hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/alex/data/kaggle.sample /user/alex/wc/output  
16/04/06 10:44:29 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/10.0.0.7:8032
16/04/06 10:44:29 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/04/06 10:44:30 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/04/06 10:44:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/04/06 10:44:30 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1459942813464_0002
16/04/06 10:44:30 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1459942813464_0002
16/04/06 10:44:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1459942813464_0002/
16/04/06 10:44:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1459942813464_0002
```

Then I goes to Hadoop Cluster Web UI, and found that the job status is ACCEPTED, and not running. I checked the log file of YARN.ResourceManager, and its last ERROR message is like this:

```
2016-04-06 10:34:42,466 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerApplicationAttempt: Error trying to assign container token and NM token to an allocated container container_1459942813464_0001_02_000001
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: worker14.alex
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:374)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.utils.BuilderUtils.newContainerToken(BuilderUtils.java:256)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTokenSecretManager.createContainerToken(RMContainerTokenSecretManager.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerApplicationAttempt.pullNewlyAllocatedContainersAndNMTokens(SchedulerApplicationAttempt.java:448)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.common.fica.FiCaSchedulerApp.getAllocation(FiCaSchedulerApp.java:269)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.allocate(CapacityScheduler.java:896)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl$AMContainerAllocatedTransition.transition(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:937)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl$AMContainerAllocatedTransition.transition(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:930)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl.handle(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:755)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl.handle(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationAttemptEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:842)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationAttemptEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:823)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:182)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:109)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: worker14.alex
... 19 more
```

The Hadoop Configuration file is following:

```
#core-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:8020/</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/alex/hadoop-2.6.3/tmp/</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
#yarn-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>master</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>/home/alex/hadoop-2.6.3/tmp/nm.local</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
        <value>/home/alex/hadoop-2.6.3/log/nm.log</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
#mapred-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
        <value>10.0.0.7:10020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
        <value>/home/alex/hadoop-2.6.3/tmp/staging</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
        <value>/home/alex/hadoop-2.6.3/tmp/mr-history/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
        <value>/home/alex/hadoop-2.6.3/tmp/mr-history/done</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`/etc/hosts` file have map ips to either master or worker1 - worker14

`slaves` file are master, worker1 - worker14

It seems that my hostname resolve goes wrong. It is `worker14.alex` rather than `worker14` (`alex` is my linux username)

So what's wrong with my configuration? Do I need to restart all the servers? Or I just need to restart some of the services like `service networking restart`?

Comment: were you able to get to a resolution? I'm seeing the exact same issue, I see a ``Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: var`` exception.

Answer (score 0):

> were you able to get to a resolution? I'm seeing the exact same issue, I see a Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: var exception. – Nishant Kelkar

Check your yarn-site.xml, this value:
`<name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>`
`<value>/var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps</value>`

If you put "hdfs://" before the path, the error occurs.

Comment: @leckieni, please post your yarn-site.xml